# テンプレートクラスで規模が大きくなるとなぜかコンパイルが通らない原因とは？

Tags: c++

提示したコードはテンプレートクラスのサンプルコードで、これは正しくコンパイルできます。
しかし提示サイトの GitHub ではこれと同じようなことをしてもコンパイルエラーが出ます。沢山出るので全部は載せられませんがどうしたらいいのでしょうか？ **Mesh.cpp Mesh.hpp** 部です。

コードが長く全部載せられないため GitHub という形を取りました。よろしくお願いします。

https://github.com/Shigurechan/OpenGL_Game

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class test
{
public:

    test();
    void f();
};

struct vert
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef vert vertex;

template<class type>
class sample : private test
{
public:
    sample(type a);
    void f();
};

// std::vector　
template<>
class sample<std::vector<vertex>> : private test
{
public:
    sample(std::vector<vertex> a);

    void f();
};
```

---

```
#include "Test.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

test::test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}

void test::f()
{
    printf("fff\n");
}

sample<std::vector<vertex>>::sample(std::vector<vertex> a) : test()
{
    printf("sample");
}

void sample<std::vector<vertex>>::f()
{
    printf("えええ\n");
}
```

Comment: 提示されているGitHubのプロジェクトだと、依存ライブラリの詳細や版数が示されていないので調査が困難と思われます。 プロジェクトの外部にインクルードパス等が設定されているようですが、NuGetパッケージで組み込んだ方が良いのでは？

Comment: プロジェクト内にライブラリファイルを追加しました。

Comment: 提示されたGitHubには`Mesh.cpp`,`Mesh.hpp`というファイルは無かったですね。`MeshComponent.cpp`,`MeshComponent.hpp`は有りました。それをMicrosoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3 の`x64 Debug`モードでビルドすると、`stb_image.cpp`というファイルで57個の`warning C4312: '型キャスト':`が発生しますが、`.exe`は出来て起動は出来るようです。`x64 Release`モードでは`61 件の未解決の外部参照`と出て`.exe`は出来ませんでしたが、コンパイルそのものは`x64 Debug`モードと同様に`warning`が出るだけで出来てはいるようです。

Comment: テンプレート化するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 結局のところ何を答えて欲しいのでしょうか？

Comment: 済みません。質問を読み違えていました。これから質問記事のソースを組み込んでみますが、テンプレート化で何を目指しているのでしょうか？ どのようになれば良いのか目安はありますか？

Comment: mehs クラスでGame::vertexattrubte 版と　Game::vertexattrubte_color版で処理を分けたいのですが。提示コードと同じようにやってもエラーが出ます。ですので提示コードをgithubに乗せるしかありませんでした。

Comment: Game::vertexattrubte 版 は https://github.com/Shigurechan/OpenGL_Game/blob/effdc82e50ceb24aa405acac565e351ad5021603/Project_OpenGL/Source/MeshComponent.cpp#L23 だと思われますが、 Game::vertexattrubte_color版のコードは見当たりません。また、kunifさんが指摘されるように「エラーが出る」と言いつつ提示されたコードはエラーが出ないため、質問の前提が成り立っていません。答えて欲しいことを質問してください。例えば、Game::vertexattrubte 版と Game::vertexattrubte_color版 の両コードを提示した上で「テンプレートで共通化したい」等。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何が如何なっていれば良いのか、が今の質問内容からは良く分かりませんが、以下のように変更するとビルドは通るようになります。

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3
x64 Debugモード

- 両方のファイル名を、`Mesh.hpp`,`Mesh.cpp`ではなく、`Test.hpp`,`Test.cpp`に変更する
  質問ソースの`Mesh.cpp`の先頭行が`#include "Test.hpp"`であり、質問の説明テキスト部分との整合性が崩れているため
- 現在は影響無いが、他の`.hpp`に合わせるために、`Test.hpp`ファイルの先頭に`#pragma once`を入れるか、他と同様に先頭と最後に`#ifndef __TEST_HPP_`で始まるインクルードガードを入れておく

質問に提示されている、ファイル・クラス・メソッドの各名前があまり具体的とは言えないことと、それらを実際に使う部分のソースが無いので、それを含めた整合性はどうなのか？ に疑問は残りますが、一応は上記でビルドが通るようになります。